# Remote desktop to multiple windows machines on a LAN with dynamic IP

Tags: windows, networking, remote-desktop, forwarding

Is it possible to use remote desktop to connect to multiple computers inside a network that has a dynamic IP address?

---

I use a netgear WPN824 router which has dyndns onboard - but I currently use No-IP to control a single computer that I use most frequently. Every so often I need to get onto a couple of other computers in the network, but don't know how to go about this without logging onto one computer, and then starting another RDC session from that machine.

What I would like to be able to do is connect to my router, and be able to see a list of connected devices, and then choose which to remote desktop onto. - I appreciate this probably is not be possible, but any other suggestions are welcome!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define multiple port forwardings on your router. E.g. If you have three machines (a,b,c), you forward it like this:

```
router:33901 -> a:3390
router:33902 -> b:3390
router:33903 -> c:3390
```

When you want to connect (let's say to a), just use

```
external.dyndns.org:33901
```

as rdp address.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I have no rep, otherwise I would have voted you up!

Answer (score 1):

Change the [default RDP port](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306759) for each of your other machines. The number must be unique for each machine.  Then apply [port forward rules](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/1002/kw/port%20forward%20rule/r_id/100109) on your router to connect to the individually assigned inside IP addresses.

When you open the Remote Desktop Connection client from outside use the same no-ip assignment that you use for your primary connection but just add :#### for what ever port number you assigned to the machine you want to connect to.

Comment: So if I start a remote desktop session, I type in username@dyndns.org:portnumber ? is that correct?

Comment: Yes, I typically use ports 5965-5969