# Using Remote Desktop to connect to different computers behind same IP

Tags: router, remote-desktop, ip

I'm trying to connect my computer from home to two computers in my office. The office has a router and I already forward the port for computer A. I can successfully connect to my computer A at my home by using static ip address. However, I am not sure how to connect to computer B since both computers use the same static IP address that is given by my ISP.

For example, at my home computer's Remote Connection box, I type `7x.8x.1xx.2xx`. That IP address is for both computers.

I'm not sure how to distinguish the computer A and computer B. Any thoughts?

Comment: You may want to try something like Teamviewer Link" http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remote desktop to multiple windows machines on a LAN with dynamic IP](http://superuser.com/questions/35675/remote-desktop-to-multiple-windows-machines-on-a-lan-with-dynamic-ip)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You can configure the port which each remote desktop is listening to. Change the port here for  computer A and B:

   ```
   HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TerminalServer\WinStations\RDP-Tcp\PortNumber
   ```
2. Forward the ports to the corresponding computers.
3. When you are connecting just specify the port: `7x.8x.1xx.2xx:23678`

Comment: I prefer doing port remapping on the router so the clients don't need touched.